# Android cant launch the emulator: emulator-5554 (OFFLINE)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just installed android studio on my new mac, but when I try to run the emulator it is written offline: emulator-5554 [OFFLINE]

Comment: did you try to relaunch that? Relaunching will resolve your issue

Comment: yes, I have been trying for hours

Comment: then delete that emulator and recreate and then launch

Comment: not work too...

Comment: I read that it could be because of the docker mac, but what is the docker?

Comment: Well I don't know about the dock.but I do know one thing. In windows we need to on virtualization feature from BIOS setting. And I don't on MAC does it require?

Comment: no I can launch the emulator, but the build it loads by saying: waiting for device to come online